# Undo Context Menu on UltraWinGrid

Tags: c#, winforms, infragistics, undo, ultrawingrid

I am trying to put up an Undo context Menu on UltraWinGrid to undo the last change that was made to the grid
The code looks like this

```
  private void _undoAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.GridName.PerformAction(Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGridAction.Undo); 

    }
```

But its not providing the desired result. I can not use DataTable UndoChanges feature because I am binding a custom class to this Grid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you set `DisplayLayout.Override.AllowMultiCellOperation` to include the flag that allows the Undo operation.

In code you should set something like this in your Form_Load event:

```
this.GridName.DisplayLayout.Override.AllowMultiCodeOperations = 
              AllowMultiCellOperation.Undo | AllowMultiCellOperation.Redo;
```

also I have found this [thread](http://community.infragistics.com/forums/p/17334/63106.aspx#63106) on Infragistics site that explain better what going on here

Comment: Did that but its not working, I am going to make it specific to my requirement now.

Comment: Answer updated with some new information from infragistics forum